# 文字がCODE128の範囲かチェックしたい

Tags: c#, アルゴリズム, winforms

掲題の件、バーコード入力でCODE128の文字をアプリ（例えば画面）で受け付けた後、
それが本当にCODE128の範囲にあるかチェックするロジックを検討しております。

例えば、正規表現で一発で出来る等の情報がありましたら
ご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

開発言語はC#で、Windows Forms画面のTextBoxでバーコード入力を受け付ける場合を
想定しています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CODE128は制御文字を含めてASCIIのすべての文字を表現できますので、

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\x00-\x7f]+$")
```

という正規表現で判定可能です。ただ通常はアプリケーション側の要件の方がCODE128仕様より厳しいと思われますので、そちら側に合わせた検証を行った方が良いと思います。